# Rolling up dependent probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, python, conditional-probability

I have a model with features and labels in a dataframe with columns like:

```
[id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_1, label_2, label_3]
```

Here the labels are 1, 0 for True, False.  I build a model for each label independently so,

```
model_1: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_1]

model_2: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_2]

model_3: [id, feature_1, feature_2, feature_2,...,feature_N, label_3]
```

So in the end I have 3 models that I can use to predict each label type and I can get
probabilities between 0 and 1 if the label_1 (2 or 3) are True/False for each row.

I want to roll up these probabilities to a single score.  The problem, however, is that these are dependent.  So if I treat them independently, I run into a situation where I might get

```
[label_1, label_2, label_3] = [1.0, 1.0, 0.001],  0.99*0.99*0.001 = 0.001
```

Now the problem here is that sometimes what we need to predict might already have label_1 and label_2 but not label_3 so we just predict label_3.  This rollup score is way too small because label_1 and label_2 are known and are True but the rollup will say that they are false - but we may not be that confident in our prediction of 0.001.  To deal with this I am using the geometric mean

```
(1.0*1.0*0.001)^(1/3) = 0.10
```

This seems to work okay but I am wondering if there a better way to to deal with this?

Comment: “ [label_1, label_2, label_3] = [1.0, 1.0, 0.001],  0.99*0.99*0.001 = 0.0001”—You may want to double check this.

Comment: One better way would be to model the joint distribution instead of modeling them independently. Do you need to keep the three models instead?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “roll up”? To me, it seems fine that you’d multiply the three probabilities to get a joint probability, given that you’re modeling the labels independently.